# Print spooler job cancellation message or callback wanted

Tags: winapi, printing, print-spooler-api

**Backgroud:**
I'm now trying to print via [GDI Print API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it looks like this:

```
StartDoc(hDC,&docinfo)
foreach page in page_buf
    StartPage(hDC)
    /* write the page to printer DC */
    EndPage(hDC)
EndDoc(hDC)
```

**The Problem:**
During printing there would be a notification area icon, and by clicking on it there would be a small window showing current printing jobs on a specified printer.
By right-clicking on a printing job and choosing `Cancel`, a printing job shall be cancelled. But my application continues sending data to the printer DC until all pages are processed, and the status keeps showing `Deleting - Spooling` before it finishes.
What I want is to stop the printing procedure right after choosing to cancel it.

**What I've tried:**
1. First I thought the device content would get invalid after cancelling the job (that's of course not true), and tried to examine the return values of [`StartPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`EndPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then I found they both don't fail after the cancellation of printing job.
2. I've also tried [`SetAbortProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`DocumentEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and found they're not what I want.

---

But I suppose there shall be some mechanism to indicate my application when the printing job is cancelled. It would be appreciated if someone tries to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is to query the print job using the [GetJob function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and terminate your loop.  The logic you want looks like this:

```
JOB_INFO_1 ji;
GetJob(...);
if (ji.Status & (JOB_STATUS_DELETED | JOB_STATUS_DELETING))
   break;
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Thank you for your help. :)